# Create specific array name with user request

Tags: java, input

OK so I want to name my array to be in a way that user wants it for example

```
String arrayName = input.next();
String[] arrayName.ValueOfMyARray;
```

so that there would be an array for example:

```
user inputs "Mehdi";
String[] Mehdi is created;
Mehdi = {18 years old, 170cm tall};
```

Comment: May I ask why, it's just a variable name? Why do you want it to be named with an input?

Comment: Variable names are pretty much only a compile-time thing. Chances are you're focusing on the wrong thing here, but we can't tell without knowing what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What should the code do or should the code change itself? Tell more clearly what you want to do.

Comment: Ok so I want to create specific arrays with specific names I know I can create an array just by doing String[] arrayName; but when it comes to specific users I would want to create specific sets of arrays for each. My goal is to create arrays which contain student information in them

Comment: If there is a better way please let me know

Comment: You could make an Object with student name and their information. You could even override toString and make it print what you want. Or of course you can use a Map.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look into a `Map`. [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: I actually figured it out. Yes using an object which takes a field of array is much easier to use. Thanks for all the feed back

Answer (score 0):

In java, you can create variables dynamically. In this case, use [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Key for the map will be the user you want.

```
Map<String, String[]> myMap = new HashMap<>();

myMap.put("Mehdi", new String[] { "18 years old", "170cm tall" });
myMap.put("Tom",   new String[] { "19 years old", "180cm tall" });

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myMap.get("Mehdi")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myMap.get("Tom")));
```

Comment: So here I create a Map that have all my arrays with the specific name right so when I say myMap.get("Mehdi") if would give me back my array?

Comment: yes, you will get back the array associated with user Mehdi.